# Is it possible to rename the Event Definition Key for a Journey Builder Entry API

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, journeybuilder

For the requirement of avoiding getting the third party to update the posts address to a new key, and continue using existing names (conveniently short and clear in where it's pointing to)...

Has anyone been able to setup a Journey Builder API Entry Event, which generates an Event Definition Key, and been able to update/customise the key after?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done, but you'll need to do this via the Entry Source.

1) Open Journey Builder tab

2) Navigate to Entry Sources

3) Create your API Entry Source with a predefined or custom API key

4) Open it again, navigate to Properties

5) Key is fully editable

Here's a screencap:

[image: JourneySource]

Comment: Amazing - it's right there and so obvious. That's Rain! 

Had just found another way to create this too - in a long way around it.

Answer (score 1):

Would recommend the straight forward approach @Rain provided on this - but here's another long way around XD...

This seemed to work for me when trying to customise an API entry event for a specific journey with a specified DE...

First, used the Journey API ID to source the other ID details (**sourceApplicationExtensionId** & **dataExtensionId**) needed to POST a new Entry Event within the relative Journey setup - in order to get that, used this;

```
GET [PARAMS =] 
https://www.exacttargetapis.com/interaction/v1/eventDefinitions/key:{API Key of Journey}
Authorization : BEARER [Paste token from above call]
Content Type: application/json
```

Then pasted those retrieved ID's into the new Event Definition POST...

```
Host: https://www.exacttargetapis.com
POST /interaction/v1/eventDefinitions
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN

    {
"type": "APIEvent",
"name": "JOURNEY_ALM_eBrochure_UAT",
"description": "Contacts submitting an eBrochure",
"mode": "Production",
"eventDefinitionKey": "UATeBrochure",
"dataExtensionId": "12345678-9101-e11e-1234-15g16hw17ie18",
"dataExtensionName": "SUBSCRIBERS_ALM_eBrochure_UAT",
"sourceApplicationExtensionId": "1grijm13-2abc-3456-78z9-de1011fg124",
"iconUrl": "/events/images/icon_journeyBuilder-event-api-blue.svg",
"arguments": {
    "serializedObjectType": 11,
    "eventDefinitionKey": "UATeBrochure",
    "dataExtensionId": "12345678-9101-e11e-1234-15g16hw17ie18",
    "criteria": "",
    "useHighWatermark": false
    },
"metaData": {
    "scheduleState": "No Schedule",
    "criteriaDescription": ""
    },
"isVisibleInPicker": true,
"category": "Event"
}
```

Went into the journey and was able to select the the API Entry Event, BUT NOT ABLE to customise anything within it, such as changes that can be done in a standard New API Entry Event Data Extension or Name.

[image: Customised Entry Event]